# Как ограничить перемещение обьекта в пространстве?

Tags: unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать чтоб игрок при перемещении не мог упасть с платформы внутрь или наружу конструкции.

Comment: добавить много коллайдеров

Comment: Если без коллайдеров, то можно предстваить конструкцию циллиндром с центральной осью - колонной, и проверять расстояние от объекта до центральной колонны, не давая смещаться за пределами определенного допустимого интервала.

Comment: Можно по направлению движения чуть поодаль рейкастить вниз. Если ни во что не упирается, то значит пропасть и нужно корректировать направление движения. Это лучше, чем коллайдер, не будет тереться об пустое пространство.

Comment: Справедливости ради, можно использовать не самый очевидный подход - кривые Безье, если речь идет про какие-то сложные формы, в которых базовые коллайдеры не помогут. Из коробки unity такое не умеет, но логику привязки и проверки "отдаленности" объекта от кривой можно написать, да и в интернете видел парочку таких библиотек.

Comment: Что насчёт Navigation? Посмотрите это видео, мне кажется оно должно помочь. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2mK6KFdv0I&t=220s

Answer (score 3):

Лично я бы импортировал в проект трубу, сделал бы ее под размер данного объекта и добавил бы `MeshCollider` на нее.

Разместив эту трубу в двух нужных местах мы получим то что нужно.(только 1 трубу нужно сделать с отрицательным Scale-ом что бы коллайдер с правильной стороны был)

При этом у объекта можно отключить MeshRenderer. То есть трубу мы сделаем невидимой.

---

Другой путь: [NavMesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-BuildingNavMesh.html)